# Getting the value of comboxbox in ExtJS

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1. My page is having a combobox and a button. The comboxbox is having a store which uses a model having 4 fields (UserName,ID (uniqueID),Age,Salary). Name is used as display field and Id is used as value field.

**What i want:**
When the button is clicked I want to see the selected value in the comboxbox and I want to *extract the salary.*

**Possible solution:** Get the id of the selected value from the combobox and find the record in the store and extract the salary for that record.

I was wondering if there is more direct approch or method exposed by ExtJS

Answer (score 0):

on combobox select you can get the `salary` value like this:

```
    onComboboxSelect: function(combo, records, options) {
    var selectedValue=combo.getValue();
    var record = combo.findRecord(combo.valueField || combo.displayField, selectedValue);
    alert(record.get('salary'));
}
```

I think this is the important then you can for example save this value and display it when the button is clicked..